# Sphinxsearch: 1064 can not use HAVING with attribute not related to GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am using the example sphinxsearch config and the 'test' database that comes with the download for version 3.1.1

```
source src1
{
type            = mysql

sql_host        = localhost
sql_user        = root
sql_pass        =
sql_db          = test
sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

sql_query       = \
    SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
    FROM documents

sql_attr_uint       = group_id
sql_attr_timestamp  = date_added
}
```

When running this:

```
$array = $sphinx->prepare("SELECT date_added,group_id FROM test1 GROUP BY group_id HAVING group_id > 1");
$array->execute();
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 can not use HAVING with attribute not related to GROUP BY
```

Comment: Why are you even using `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: As an example to show the error, I need the HAVING clause to work this way for a different query

Comment: Well show us the real query please.

Answer (score 2):

Use `where condition` instead of `having` since you didn't use any `aggregation` also `group by` is not necessary in this case

```
SELECT date_added,group_id 
FROM test1 
where group_id>1
```